# Order by meta_value in SQL request

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I want to order my result by the number of likes. I need to use a sql request instead of a new query args.

Inside a regular query, I should use
`'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'`
but because it is a sql request I use 
`ORDER BY {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_value DESC;`

This is what I tried:

```
$test = $wpdb->get_results ( "
SELECT * 
FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
WHERE post_id LIKE '$get_the_ID_090909%' AND {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_key = '_liked' AND {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_value > 0
ORDER BY {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_value DESC;
        " );
        echo ' '.$test[0]->meta_value; // 2
        echo ' '.$test[1]->meta_value; // 14
        echo ' '.$test[2]->meta_value; // 10
```

The right order should be :

```
14
10
2
```

Please note that if I use "ASC", the order is 10, 14, 2
And if I change the like number, it DOES change the position. Sometimes it is the right order depending of the number of likes

var_dump() :

```
 array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#7998 (4) { ["meta_id"]=> string(3) "756" ["post_id"]=> string(12) "179090909185" ["meta_key"]=> string(6) "_liked" ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "2" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#8000 (4) { ["meta_id"]=> string(3) "696" ["post_id"]=> string(12) "179090909176" ["meta_key"]=> string(6) "_liked" ["meta_value"]=> string(2) "14" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#8001 (4) { ["meta_id"]=> string(3) "697" ["post_id"]=> string(12) "179090909170" ["meta_key"]=> string(6) "_liked" ["meta_value"]=> string(2) "10" } }
```

Comment: try var_dump($test) and post the results

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#7998 (4) { ["meta_id"]=> string(3) "756" ["post_id"]=> string(12) "179090909185" ["meta_key"]=> string(6) "_liked" ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "2" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#8000 (4) { ["meta_id"]=> string(3) "696" ["post_id"]=> string(12) "179090909176" ["meta_key"]=> string(6) "_liked" ["meta_value"]=> string(2) "14" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#8001 (4) { ["meta_id"]=> string(3) "697" ["post_id"]=> string(12) "179090909170" ["meta_key"]=> string(6) "_liked" ["meta_value"]=> string(2) "10" } } Mis à jour il y a 10 heures • 3 produits recommandés

Comment: I posted the result @Vishwa

Comment: The column `meta_value` is a varchar, which means that the numbers are sorted as strings, not as numbers. Try casting the column as int when sorting. Try something like: `ORDER BY CAST({$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) ASC`.

Comment: Also, when adding output/code, edit your question to include it instead of posting large chunks of code/output as a comment.

Comment: It's working ! Can you post an answer ? or do I edit my question to put the answer?

Comment: @Youstart - I've posted it as an answer

Comment: @Youstart Magnu is right. did his answer worked for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column `meta_value` is a varchar, which means that all values (including numbers) are being sorted as strings.

Cast the column as INT when sorting:

```
ORDER BY CAST({$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```